# Importing project successful in windows fails in linux

Tags: java, eclipse

When performing an `Import -> Team -> Team Project Set` and pointing to a `psf` file I get the following error.

```
Error While Importing Project Sets

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Clicking `details` just repeats the error. I can't seem to find any help on the net, however I tried installing on my windows machine as a test, and it worked fine. As far as I can tell I have the same configuration (jdk 1.7, eclipse luna, and the same mercurial plugins/etc).

Any help?

Additional information:

```
Log contents contain a variety of null pointer exceptions.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2015-05-06 14:22:34.740
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.getSourcePart(ShowInMenu.java:334)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.fillMenu(ShowInMenu.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.fill(ShowInMenu.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.doItemFill(MenuManager.java:780)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.update(MenuManager.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1412)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1393)
```

Additionally it is complaining about proxy information, I am going to try working through that first (although the project I'm referencing are located on mounted locations, thus no http proxy needed I expect)

EDIT:
After reading through the log and figuring out all the errors.
I added my username to the ~/.hgrc and adding my user to be trusted.

When importing the project now it's just sitting there, no status, nothing, just "working" for quite a while.

I checked the log and no problems listed (errors or warnings).

Comment: What does your Eclipse log file say? (`<workspace dir>/.log`)

Comment: ls -la shows NO .log files. Neither in the workspace dir/ folder nor in the project folder inside

Comment: sorry, I mean `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the big problem I ran into is that the repository I was trying to clone is on a server, and when I was cloning, either the network would drop out, or the connection was too slow and it would fail. (Multi GB repo) I finally sorted that out by cloning on my host machine and pointing to those folders, it's not a perfect solution but it works.